# fetching json data using yql from yahoo finance.quotes is not working from 01/11/2017 22:00

Tags: yql

I am getting an empty result from yahoo finance when i use the api to table yahoo.finance.quotes 
I used your query to check the interface and the result is NULL. Apparently there is a malfunction.
steps for testing: 
go to https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/
show community tables
Mark checkbox: show community tables
uncheck: DIAGNOSTICS 
Select a table: finance.quotes
A default query will appear
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")
The result

{
 "query": {
  "count": 0,
  "created": "2017-11-02T13:21:01Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": null
 }
}

Comment: Please read how to ask a question and format the question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Very sadly and quite outrageously Yahoo decided to stop this service without any warning.

See admin message [here](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/http-download-finance-yahoo-com-d-quotes-csv-s-GOOG-amp-f/td-p/387096)
[image: Yahoo screenshot - Admin says no more finance API]

So many services depend on it, it's like Google saying they would suddenly stop their maps API... At this point I am blocking yahoo in our DNS so no one in our company will ever use Yahoo again since they are not a reliable entity.